# ffmpeg produced .wav reads only zeros with scipy.io.wavfile

Tags: ffmpeg, scipy, wav

Hi everyone and thanks for reading.

I wanted to do some analysis on a song using Python's **scipy.io.wavfile**. Since I only have the song as .mp3 I converted the file to .wav using **ffmpeg** the following way:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 test.wav
```

The .wav file plays perfectly well with vlc player, but wavfile shows only zeroes when reading it:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile as wf

data = wf.read("test.wav")
C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py:42: WavFileWarning: Unknown wave file format
  warnings.warn("Unknown wave file format", WavFileWarning)

data
(44100, array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]], dtype=int16))
```

I tried getting the data with Python's built-in **wave** module before to the same effect (only zeros).
I am using the 64bit version of ffmpeg (ffmpeg-20140218-git-61d5970-win64-static).

Any help is appreciated :-)

### Edit: Included .wav header and tried forcing ffmpeg output format

I guess the header information of the .wav file is included here:

```
ffmpeg -i .\test.wav
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from '.\test.wav':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Joe Cocker
    copyright       : (C) 1987 Capitol Records, Inc.
    date            : 1987
    genre           : Pop
    title           : Unchain My Heart
    album           : Unchain My Heart
    track           : 1/10
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:05:04.33, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

If I try to specify the ffmpeg output format explicitly for the .mp3 conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i .\test.mp3 -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 test.wav
Input #0, mp3, from '.\test.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Unchain My Heart
    artist          : Joe Cocker
    album           : Unchain My Heart
    genre           : Pop
    composer        : Bobby Sharp
    track           : 1/10
    disc            : 1/1
    album_artist    : Joe Cocker
    copyright       : (C) 1987 Capitol Records, Inc.
    date            : 1987
  Duration: 00:05:04.35, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 240 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 235 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 600x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           :
      comment         : Cover (front)
Output #0, s16le, to 'test.wav':
  Metadata:
    title           : Unchain My Heart
    artist          : Joe Cocker
    album           : Unchain My Heart
    genre           : Pop
    composer        : Bobby Sharp
    track           : 1/10
    disc            : 1/1
    album_artist    : Joe Cocker
    copyright       : (C) 1987 Capitol Records, Inc.
    date            : 1987
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 -> pcm_s16le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
video:0kB audio:52425kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000000%
size=   52425kB time=00:05:04.32 bitrate=1411.2kbits/s
```

But in this case (forced format), both ffmpeg and wavfile are not able to read the file:

```
ffmpeg -i .\test.wav
.\test.wav: Invalid data found when processing input
```

and

```
data = wf.read("test2.wav")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fbbd84cb966b> in <module>()
----> 1 data = wf.read("test2.wav")

C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.pyc in read(filename, mmap)
    152 
    153     try:
--> 154         fsize = _read_riff_chunk(fid)
    155         noc = 1
    156         bits = 8

C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.pyc in _read_riff_chunk(fid)
     98         _big_endian = True
     99     elif str1 != b'RIFF':
--> 100         raise ValueError("Not a WAV file.")
    101     if _big_endian:
    102         fmt = '>I'

ValueError: Not a WAV file.
```

Comment: Without the file or some information about it (file header for example), it's hard to say where the 'Unknown wave file format' warning comes from.

Comment: Try specify output PCM format explicitly, e.g. `-f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2` (signed 16bit integer PCM format stereo, 44.1khz). With ffmpeg `-formats` argument you can view the list of supported formats.

Comment: @9dan Hi! I tried specifying the format for the .mp3 conversion, but the corresponding output .wav is not readable by either ffmpeg, scipy or vlc. The output file's size was the same as with default conversion, though.

Comment: @sebix Hi! I included what I believe is information on the .wav file header.

Comment: Sorry to ask a dumb question, but are you sure the array is all zeros?  The first time you did `data = wf.read("test.wav")`, did you check, say, `data[1].max()` and `data[1].min()`?  (I only ask because I just tried this on an mp3, and I also saw `array([[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], ..., [0, 0]])`, but that was because the beginning and end of the file were, in fact, zeros; nonzero values didn't start until index 1500 or so.)

Comment: can you run `soxi` on the wav file and post the outcome?

Comment: @Warren There are no dumb questions, just dumb mistakes... Actally most of the array is nonzero, but the nonzero entries don't start until index 40000 or so. I checked the first 10000, but not the rest. Thanks!

Comment: @question_mark  Have you solved this problem?  I ran into the same thing today.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.  This seems to be a bug in FFmpeg that was introduced in October 2011 that was fixed April 29, 2014 (5e7d21c7ad02e37caa1bcb50ab8ad64e7d7fb86c).  FFmpeg versions more recent than 2.3 (July 16, 2014) should write WAVs that numpy can read without error.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg 2.5 and the problem still exists.  (using Ubuntu.  when I use ffmpeg on Windows, everything is fine.)